# Show equivalent value of multiple columns from one column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

### The structure

I have 3 tables:

The first one is the [equipment] table:

```
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
| equip_id | chara_id | weapon_id | headgear_id | armor_id | ring_id |
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
|        3 |        1 |         3 |           3 |        5 |       6 |
|        4 |        2 |         1 |           2 |        3 |       4 |
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
```

The second one is the [item] table:

```
+---------+--------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------+-----------+------------+
| item_id | item_name    | item_type | item_atk | item_def | item_atr | item_img                      | item_desc | item_price |
+---------+--------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------+-----------+------------+
|       0 | Halberd      |         1 |      220 |       20 |        0 | pics/weapons/halberd.png      |           |        400 |
|       1 | Axe          |         1 |      220 |      -10 |        0 | pics/weapons/axe.png          |           |        200 |
|       2 | Wooden Sword |         1 |       70 |        0 |        0 | pics/weapons/wooden-sword.png |           |        225 |
|       3 | Dagger       |         1 |       60 |        5 |        0 | pics/weapons/dagger.png       |           |         55 |
|       4 | Bow          |         1 |      120 |        1 |        0 | pics/weapons/bow.png          |           |          0 |
|       5 | Helmet       |         4 |        0 |       20 |        0 | pics/headgear/helmet.png      |           |        155 |
|       6 | Tunic        |         2 |        0 |       10 |        0 | pics/armors/tunic.png         |           |         50 |
|       7 | Armour       |         2 |        0 |       45 |        0 | pics/armors/armour.png        |           |          0 |
|       8 | Necklace     |         3 |       15 |        5 |        0 | pics/accessories/necklace.png |           |        199 |
+---------+--------------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------+-----------+------------+
```

and the last one is the [chara] table:

```
+----------+------------+----------------+------------+
| chara_id | chara_name | chara_class_id | chara_gold |
+----------+------------+----------------+------------+
|        1 | Lawrence   |              1 |          0 |
|        2 | Testo      |              0 |          0 |
|        3 | Viscocent  |              2 |          0 |
|        4 | Piatos     |              1 |          0 |
|        5 | Hello      |              4 |          0 |
+----------+------------+----------------+------------+
```

### My hurdle:

I want to to display the equivalent `item_name`(from item table) of each `weapon_id`, `armor_id`, `headgear_id` and `ring_id`(all from equipment table) from a selected character.
e.g:

weapon_id: 1 => item_name from items table
  armor_id: 3 => item_name from items table
  etc..

expected result:
when i query the equipment of a character it returns the weapon name and not the weapon id .

---------------
chara_id: 1
Weapon: Dagger
Headgear: Dagger (character data is sample doesn’t matter as long as it returns the item_name)
Armor: Helmet
Ring: Tunic

This can be simply be solved with 4 queries but I don't want to use 4 queries, if there is a better solution.

Comment: Are you screaming at us in all caps or using lazy txt-speak? Make up your mind.

Comment: erm.. sorry i dont scream, just title formatting for me

Comment: Screaming in all caps is not any kind of sensible formatting. Learn markdown.

Comment: Could you please post your expected result?

Comment: ok, please wait a bit

Comment: What is the relationship of `item` table with other two table?

Comment: though this is already answered: 'chara' table has an equivalent of a set of items(weapon_id, headgear_id, armor_id, ring_id) in the 'equipment' row which only cointains the id of an item. now i want to get there equivalent item_name from the 'item' table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT e.chara_id,
       e.weapon_id, i1.item_name weapon_name,
       e.headgear_id, i2.item_name headgear_name,
       e.armor_id, i3.item_name armor_name,
       e.ring_id, i4.item_name ring_name
  FROM equipment e LEFT JOIN
       item i1 ON e.weapon_id = i1.item_id LEFT JOIN
       item i2 ON e.headgear_id = i2.item_id LEFT JOIN
       item i3 ON e.armor_id = i3.item_id LEFT JOIN
       item i4 ON e.ring_id = i4.item_id 
 WHERE e.chara_id = 1
```

Output

```
| CHARA_ID | WEAPON_ID | WEAPON_NAME | HEADGEAR_ID | HEADGEAR_NAME | ARMOR_ID | ARMOR_NAME | RING_ID | RING_NAME |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        1 |         3 |      Dagger |           3 |        Dagger |        5 |     Helmet |       6 |     Tunic |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6379/5)**

*If you don't need ids in your resultset at all just ditch them from query*

Comment: ah .. one row .. smooth .. I bow

Comment: sorry i cannot vote you up yet...  nid more reputation but certainly u ar the sql mastah.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join

```
SELECT c.chara_name as name, i.item_name
FROM chara c
  LEFT JOIN equipment AS e ON c.chara_id = e.chara_id
  LEFT JOIN item AS i ON i.id = e.item_id
WHERE c.chara_id = 1
```

you may get multiple rows to deal with .. but it'll be one query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT e.equip_id, w.item_name AS weapon, a.item_name AS armor, 
    h.item_name AS headgear, r.item_name AS ring
FROM equipment e
INNER JOIN item AS w ON (w.item_id = e.weapon_id)
INNER JOIN item AS a ON (w.item_id = e.armor_id)
INNER JOIN item AS h ON (w.item_id = e.headgear_id)
INNER JOIN item AS r ON (w.item_id = e.ring_id)
```

;-)